# returning a list from a function on rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am stuck at something silly. I have an rdd x. On each element of this rdd, I have to call a function f which takes element from this rdd and adds it to a list.

```
    var list1 = scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[String]()
        def listfinal (x:String):scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[String]={
                list1 += x
                return list1
     }
    val s = rdd.map(x=>listfinal(x))
    print(s.count())
```

I want only the last list out of it where all the elements of the rdd have been added and not every list which contains elements from rdd successively. How do i do it?

Comment: I don't want to sound mean or rude but this is just bad programming. Have you read at least some documentation ?

Comment: Not much really. I am beginning to do it and practicing along side. could you please elaborate a bit on making it good?

Comment: Further, I have put only relevant part of the code.

Comment: If your data fits on memory and in a list, spark would be an overhead.

Comment: our data has some 250 million data points which is some 100 GB that's why we are using spark. This data is stored in HBase and then we are making an RDD out of it to process faster.

Comment: And you want to fit 250M entries into a list. Please tell me how is that possible !

Comment: wouldn't the above code part do it? If not, that's why I am here.

Comment: @eliasah Thanks. This indeed is a bad programming. Will get into documentation first.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that Spark operates on copies of all the variables used in the function. Therefore, no updates to the variables are propagated back to the driver program, where you define your list. See [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/programming-guide.html#shared-variables) for more details.

To gather all elements of an RDD to a list, consider the `aggregate()` action.
Supposing you have an RDD of Strings, then your solution will look like:

```
rdd.aggregate(List[String]())((list, element) => element :: list, _ ++ _)
```